# How to check if string contains '?' using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if an url contains a query string or not. 
Lets say we have these two url's.

```
http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list

http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list?resource=de
```

My string is called fullPath, and I need to check if it contains the ?, so I know if its a query string or not.

Have tried with the following code:

```
if (fullPath.indexOf("?") > -1){
    content = fs-readFileSync('http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list1');
}
else {
    content = fs.readFileSync(fullPath);
}
```

Comment: You are already doing it right.

Comment: does this "fullPath.indexOf("?") > -1" not worked for you  ?

Comment: You've tried, but is it not working?

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Second line should be `.` not `-`

Comment: yeah +1 for @simonKirsten the mistake is not from your indexOf, it's from your "fs-readFileSync" instead of "fs.readFileSync"

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (str.indexOf("?") >= 0)
```

Or,

```
if (/\?/i.test(str))
```

Or,

```
if(str.includes('?'))
```

Please note that String.includes is an EcmaScript 6 feature and may not work in some browsers.

Comment: '?' is a special character in regex, so in your second answer above you might want to change that to /\?/i

Comment: Please note that `String.includes` is an EcmaScript 6 feature and may not work in some browsers. You can visit [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for more information and a polyfill.

Comment: would it be ok @0x539 if  I add your comment in my answer?

Comment: Sure. It's important to know about this and improves the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your way should work too but if you want in the future to use more complex qualifiers you could start using regular expressions:

```
var pattern = /\?/g;
var found = fullPath.match(pattern) != null;
alert(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head> 
        <body>
           <script>
               var str = "this is ?text";
               var patt = /\?/gi;
               if(str.search(patt)!=-1)
                   alert("Found");
               else
                   alert("No found");
            </script>
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is just to check if there's a php get variable right??

```
if(document.localtion.search != "") {
   // Your code
}
```

The document.location.search will  be "?resource=de" if you visit the url

http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list?resource=de

And it will be "" if you visit the url

http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list

**Answer #2**

```
check = document.location.split("?");

    if(check.length > 1) {
       //do your code
    }
```

splitting the http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list?resource=de url using "?" will be splitted by 2.

And splitting the http://localhost:3000/userbookings/list url using "?" wil result by 1.

**Answer #3**

```
check = fullpath.replace("?","");
if(check != fullpath) {
   //do your code
}
```

Removing the "?" in the full path. If the check is the same as fullpath then it doesn't have a "?"

I think this might help you out. Feel free to comment